Apps script using data from Sheets fails to send from Gmail account without returning any errors
I need to automate sending emails to a list of recipients stored in a Google spreadsheet. I'm new to Apps Script and Javascript but made some simple code based on tutorials that fit what I need.
My sheet includes columns for the email address, subject, and body text.
There is also a single cell, F2,  for a common BCC address that is used by all rows.
I have a column with a checkbox to indicate if a row should be included.
When I run the script to send an email to myself, it executes without error, but I never receive the email.
Sample Data
Link to a sample Google spreadsheet




A
B
C
D
E
F




1
People
Send
Email
Subject
Body
Blind Carbon Copy


2
name01
☑
email01
subject01
body01
common_bcc_address


3
name02
☑
email02
subject02
body02



4
name03
☐
email03
subject03
body03





The same BCC address, located in F2, is used for all messages, not just the first row.
For each row, an email should only be sent if column B is checked.
The sheet is named People1

Script
function sendEmails() {
  var ss  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('People1');
  var values = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  var ebcc = ss.getRange(2, 6).getValue()

  for (var i = 0; i > values.length ;i++){
    if (values[i][3] == true) {  
      var theEmail = ss.getRange(i,3).getValue();
      var theSubject = ss.getRange(i,4).getValue();
      var theBody = ss.getRange(i,5).getValue();
      GmailApp.sendEmail(theEmail, theSubject, theBody, {bcc: ebcc})
      }
  }
}


i < values.length

try:
function sendEmails() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('People1');
  var values = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  var ebcc = ss.getRange(2, 6).getValue();

  for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][3] == true) {  
      var theEmail = values[i][0];
      var theSubject = values[i][1];
      var theBody = values[i][2];
      GmailApp.sendEmail(theEmail, theSubject, theBody, {bcc: ebcc});
    }
  }
}


changed i > values.length to i < values.length to ensure the loop iterates through each row of data
changed ss.getRange(i, 3).getValue() to values[i][0], values[i][1], and values[i][2] respectively, ensuring data is correctly accessed from the values array (assuming email, subject, and body are in the first, second, and third columns respectively)
adjusted to start i from 1 instead of 0 to skip the header row


TL;DR



Error in script
Correction 




> values.length
< values.length


values[i][3]
values[i][1]



Adapted Script
This is how I would adapt your script:
function sendEmails() {
  const ss  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('People1');
  const values = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  values.forEach(r => (r[1] == true) &&
    GmailApp.sendEmail(r[2],r[3],r[4],{bcc: values[1][5]}));
}

Your Approach
If you prefer your original approach, here it is updated:
function sendEmails() {
  const ss  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('People1');
  const values = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  const ebcc = values[1][5];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
    if (values[i][1] == true) {  
      let theEmail = values[i][2];
      let theSubject = values[i][3];
      let theBody = values[i][4];
      GmailApp.sendEmail(theEmail, theSubject, theBody, {bcc: ebcc})
    }
  }
}

Notes:

As @TheMaster commented, your for loop should have < values.length not > values.length
Even with the previous item corrected, none of the rows would ever be processed because if (values[i][3] == true) is never true:

While columns and rows may start at 1, array indexes start at 0 so you need to be aware of whether you are referring to an array index or a row/column number.
3 in values[i][3] specifies the value from Column D (Column 4) whereas your checkboxes are in Column B (Column 2). So, to refer to the value from Column B, you would use values[i][1]


While you retrieve all the values from the Sheet in the third row of your script using ss.getDataRange().getValues(), you then retrieve needed values again which is unnecessary and delays your script with extra calls. For example,

const ebcc = ss.getRange(2,6).getValue() should beconst ebcc = values[1][5]
let theEmail = ss.getRange(i,3).getValue()
should belet theEmail = values[i][2]


I used a forEach() loop instead of for, but either will work.


Thank you for your answer. These scripts still go over my head, but I hope I learn them in time. I have tired your approach, but for some reason it didn't work for me. The one form player0 did work however, so I have the solution now.

I did it based on the sample data. The other answer has email in column 1 and the checkbox in 4.
